# How to show website the same way on phone like on PC

Tags: web, mobile, responsive-design, resolution

Is there any way to show my website exactly the same way how it works on PC, tablets or notebook? I've got full HD laptop and i'm using Chrome - everything works great. On my tablet 10" I also have full HD resolution and Chrome and my website shows like this one on notebook. When I try to to show it on my full HD Lumia 1520 it's crap. I don't use Chrome here so I can understand that some element can be broken by interpreter but it's so approximate that every element go on the others. It looks like 640x480.

Is it some way to force approximate?

Answer (score 0):

If the site developed is not responsive according to the screen size it will not display the content present on it in well manner, you must use bootstrap in your website to make it responsive for all kind of screen resolutions. It may has problem in the CSS. So check the css you used.

Comment: I know it isn't responsive design at all, but it shouldn't matter. At least I hope so. I always thought responsive is only "better" way to display website on mobile devices but it seems to be "only" way :( Website to display need browser interpreter + display resolution and any other components do not change - logic is always the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Logic is the same but, the look and fill matters with the use of css and bootstrap. so according to the screen resolution it always get change.

Comment: Of course! According to screen resolution - that's right! But I've got everywhere full HD resolution, on every device - how about that? That what I'm fighting with... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use meta tag called view-port. There are different situations and you may set up your website appearance with media queries for responsive results or manage it for being non-responsive but comfortable.

If you need second result - don't use any responsive frameworks or prevent them of using responsive techniques.

There are to much different situations so I can help only if you'll show me the code you have.